# How to use CASE WHEN THEN inside aggregated SELECT with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an aggregated GROUP BY query that worked fine until I added the CASE statement. After adding that I get this error:

```
"Column 'gym.SalesDocumentItems.SalesDocumentItemStatusID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

Here is the query:

```
select 
    a.AccountID, 
    isnull(sum(sdi.TotalAmount),0) AS Amount,
    isnull(sum(sdi.TotalDiscountAmount),0) AS Discount,
    isnull(sum(sdi.TaxAmount),0) AS TaxAmount, 
    isnull(sum(sdi.TaxDiscountAmount),0) AS TaxDiscountAmount, 
    isnull(sum(sdi.AmountPaid),0) AS AmountPaid,
    isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0) * -1 AS Credit,
    CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN
        isnull(sum(sdi.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(sdi.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0)
    ELSE
        -isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0)
    END
    AS Balance,
    r.RunningBalanceTotal,
    isnull(sum(sdi.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(sdi.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0) - r.RunningBalanceTotal AS Difference,
    isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0) AS AccountCredit
from gym.Account a
join gym.SalesDocument sd
on a.AccountID = sd.AccountID
join gym.SalesDocumentItems sdi
on sd.salesdocumentid = sdi.salesdocumentid
join RunningBalanceTotals r
on a.AccountID = r.AccountID
group by a.AccountID, a.CreditAmountAvailable, r.RunningBalanceTotal
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this. I need the case statement so that the select behaves differently for different circumstances. For any record in which sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3), I need the the full calculation; otherwise I merely need the negative of CreditAmountAvailable.

How can I achieve this? I am using MS SQL Server 2012.

[[EDIT]]

Here is a modified query based on Frank's query below:

```
WITH ungrouped as (
    SELECT a.AccountID, 
           sdi.TotalAmount,
           CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS method,
           sdi.TaxAmount,
           sdi.TotalDiscountAmount,
           sdi.TaxDiscountAmount,
           sdi.AmountPaid,
           a.CreditAmountAvailable,
           r.RunningBalanceTotal
      from gym.Account a
      join gym.SalesDocument sd
      on a.AccountID = sd.AccountID
      join gym.SalesDocumentItems sdi
      on sd.salesdocumentid = sdi.salesdocumentid
      join RunningBalanceTotals r
      on a.AccountID = r.AccountID
)
SELECT ungrouped.AccountID, 
       CASE WHEN ungrouped.method = 1 THEN
            isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0)
       ELSE
            -isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0)
       END AS Balance,
       ungrouped.RunningBalanceTotal,
       isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0) - ungrouped.RunningBalanceTotal AS Difference,
       isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0) AS Credit
  FROM ungrouped
  where ungrouped.AccountID IN (    4238534,    4231337,    4132170, 4100923, 4137728, 4143255,     4230150, 4238565 
  )
GROUP BY ungrouped.AccountID, ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable, ungrouped.RunningBalanceTotal, ungrouped.method
ORDER BY ungrouped.AccountID
```

Comment: Do the select first in a common table expression, and then do the additional join and case work on that common table expression.

Comment: Can each row in `sdi` (for each `a.AccountID` that is being grouped) have a different values in `SalesDocumentItemStatusID`?  If so (for example, one row has a `1` and another has a `2`), how should that be handled?  Please could you include some sample data that shows how to handle such corner cases?  *(Both the raw data, and the final results.  Please simplify the example to only cover the aspects of the code that you are having trouble with.)*

Comment: Each row in sdi can have a different SalesDocumentItemStatusID. For any row with SDI of 2 or 4, all I need are 0s really, if that's simpler. I can handle CreditAmountAvailable in other ways easily. But if I set SalesDocumentItemStatusID in the where clause, rows disappear and I can't have that. I'd rather have 0s be summed along with other amounts, or have all 0s, but not missing records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fetch all your columns and include the first part of the `CASE` logic, but no grouping into a CTE, which I called `ungrouped`. Then, do the grouping and include the result of the CASE of the CTE in the `GROUP BY`:

```
    WITH ungrouped as (
    SELECT a.AccountID, 
           sdi.TotalAmount,
           CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS method,
           sdi.TaxAmount,
           sdi.TotalDiscountAmount,
           sdi.TaxDiscountAmount,
           sdi.AmountPaid,
           a.CreditAmountAvailable,
           r.RunningBalanceTotal
      from gym.Account a
      join gym.SalesDocument sd
      on a.AccountID = sd.AccountID
      join gym.SalesDocumentItems sdi
      on sd.salesdocumentid = sdi.salesdocumentid
      join RunningBalanceTotals r
      on a.AccountID = r.AccountID
)
SELECT ungrouped.AccountID, 
       isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalAmount),0) AS Amount,
       isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalDiscountAmount),0) AS Discount,
       isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxAmount),0) AS TaxAmount, 
       isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxDiscountAmount),0) AS TaxDiscountAmount, 
       isnull(sum(ungrouped.AmountPaid),0) AS AmountPaid,
       isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0) * -1 AS Credit,
       CASE WHEN ungrouped.method = 1 THEN
            isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0)
            ELSE
                -isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0)
       END AS Balance,
       ungrouped.RunningBalanceTotal,
       isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0) - ungrouped.RunningBalanceTotal AS Difference,
       isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0) AS AccountCredit
  FROM ungrouped
GROUP BY ungrouped.AccountID, ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable, ungrouped.RunningBalanceTotal, ungrouped.method
```

Comment: Frank, sorry but I'm a bit confused. Any chance you could post the full working query? You have my original query, and since you know what you're doing with this and I don't, it seems like you could put it together in seconds.

Comment: @SweatCoder I edited my answer. Sorry, I had thought that simply giving an example of each type of column, one normal and the one with the case would be enough, and would more clearly point to the things to change.

Comment: This looks very promising, but there is 1 troubling problem. For some accounts I get 2 records. Please see screenshot of result set: http://www.refslot.com/temp/results.png  -- For account 4137728 I get 2 records. One of them has exactly correct amounts, and the other is wrong. Any idea why 2 sets of results? I suspect it probably means that that account has some records with statusid 1,3, and others not. So we get 2 sets. Any thoughts on this? It's super close to perfect, but this is a real problem.

Comment: I modified my original post with a mod of your query, so you can see the sql that generates the resultset shown in the screenshot in previous comment. I hope you can point me in the right direction on this.

Comment: @SweatCoder I would assume there are one or more records having a `SalesDocumentItemStatusID` of 1 or 3 and one or more that have a `SalesDocumentItemStatusID` other than 1 or 3 for this `AccountID`. You could validate this assumption by adding `ungrouped.method` to the outer select list. Then you should see both values, 1, and 2 for the data that is not as you expect.

Comment: @SweatCoder Do I understand correctly that the requirement is: if there exist several different `SalesDocumentItemStatusID`s for the same `AccountID`, `CreditAmountAvailable`, and `RunningBalanceTotal`, then `isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(ungrouped.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0)` should be applied, and `-isnull(ungrouped.CreditAmountAvailable,0)` only if no record with id 1 or 3 exists?

Comment: Frank, you got me almost home on this. Far enough. I can take it the rest of the way. Thanks! NOTE: I edited your sql because it was breaking. A few minor tweaks got it working correctly, so the edit is there, but I guess it's invisible until it's peer reviewed.

Comment: Frank, to answer your latest, it seems a pattern is emerging. I always get either 1 or 2 records per account. When I get 2 records, if the "method" is 1, the amounts are right, and if "2" the amounts are wrong. I'm analyzing to see if this is always true. If it is, I'm home free. Otherwise I have some heavy lifting to do still.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments to your original question, I see the requirement is to use a zero in the summation if the `sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID` is different from 1 or 3. This can be handled by dragging the `CASE` into the summation:

```
select 
    a.AccountID, 
    isnull(sum(sdi.TotalAmount),0) AS Amount,
    isnull(sum(sdi.TotalDiscountAmount),0) AS Discount,
    isnull(sum(sdi.TaxAmount),0) AS TaxAmount, 
    isnull(sum(sdi.TaxDiscountAmount),0) AS TaxDiscountAmount, 
    isnull(sum(sdi.AmountPaid),0) AS AmountPaid,
    isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0) * -1 AS Credit,

      isnull(sum(CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN sdi.TotalAmount ELSE 0 END),0)
    - isnull(sum(CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN sdi.TotalDiscountAmount ELSE 0 END),0)
    + isnull(sum(CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN sdi.TaxAmount ELSE 0 END),0)
    - isnull(sum(CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN sdi.TaxDiscountAmount ELSE 0 END),0)
    - isnull(sum(CASE WHEN sdi.SalesDocumentItemStatusID IN(1,3) THEN sdi.AmountPaid ELSE 0 END),0)
    - isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0)
    AS Balance,

    r.RunningBalanceTotal,
    isnull(sum(sdi.TotalAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.TotalDiscountAmount),0) + isnull(sum(sdi.TaxAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.TaxDiscountAmount),0) - isnull(sum(sdi.AmountPaid),0) - isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0) - r.RunningBalanceTotal AS Difference,
    isnull(a.CreditAmountAvailable,0) AS AccountCredit
from gym.Account a
join gym.SalesDocument sd
on a.AccountID = sd.AccountID
join gym.SalesDocumentItems sdi
on sd.salesdocumentid = sdi.salesdocumentid
join RunningBalanceTotals r
on a.AccountID = r.AccountID
group by a.AccountID, a.CreditAmountAvailable, r.RunningBalanceTotal
```